# Mandrill webhook callback

Tags: php, symfony, mandrill

I try to use Mandrill's webhook on my app running with Symfony 2.

I use a free account which allow me to send ~2000 mails for free, but I know it's impossible to test some features (like async sendings).

So :

- I send an email and I receive it
- My callback URL is called with a POST request (webhook send triggered)

My controller code :

```
  /**
   * @Route("/")
   * @Method({"HEAD", "POST"})
   */
  public function handleWebhookAction(Request $request) {
    $events = $request->request->get('mandrill_events');
    error_log($events);
  }
```

The issue is that $events is empty, it should contains information about the message.

How can I handle it ?

Thanks.